# Why was I awarded the Vox Populi Badge?

Tags: bug

It says I used the maximum of 40 votes in a day but I've only voted on a couple of things in the last 48 hours.  Is something being updated or do I simply not understand the badge?

The [page that shows the recent history](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/66/vox-populi?userid=2648) for this badge said there were 93 not 10 minutes ago, but now it says 21 so something is clearly out of sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just deployed a change that affects the voting badges.  This is why you see a number of these badges being awarded.

For more information about this change, you can see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/140548).

Note that there was a bug with Vox Populi only that awarded too many of them (beyond the expected more for retroactive awards) and a fix has been deployed.  The erroneous awards have been cleaned up.